How to pass a generic value as function parameter
I need to pass a generic Type to a function, but I get this error:
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'PullSearch3Input' to 'IInputModel<InputModelParametersBase>'

The code to reproduce the compilation error:
async Task GetFromCacheAsync(IInputModel<InputModelParametersBase> oInputParams)
{
}

async Task PullSearch3(PullSearch3Input oInputParams)
{
    await GetFromCacheAsync(oInputParams);
}

public class PullSearch3Input : InputModelBase<PullSearch3Parameters>
{
}

public class PullSearch3Parameters : InputModelParametersPagination
{
    public string QueryWord { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class InputModelParametersPagination : InputModelParametersToken
{
    public int Start { get; set; }

    public int Rows { get; set; } = 20;

    public InputModelParametersPagination()
    { }
}

public class InputModelParametersToken : InputModelParametersBase
{
    public string StaticToken { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public InputModelParametersToken()
    { }
}

public class InputModelParametersBase
{
    public InputModelParametersBase()
    { }
}

public class InputModelBase<T> : InputModelBaseBase<T> where T : InputModelParametersToken, new()
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
}

public class InputModelBaseBase<T> : IInputModel<T> where T : InputModelParametersBase, new()
{
    public bool Trace { get; set; }
    public T Parameters { get; set; } = new T();
}

public interface IInputModel<T>
{
    public bool Trace { get; set; }

    public T Parameters { get; set; }
}


